# Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less than method

Tags: c#, visibility

I know the question `inconsistent accessibility` is frequently asked, and my question is different because I need it to be private.

Let me give the detailed explaination: I have a **static** class `Line`, and a struct `LingSegment` in `Line`, users can define their own `LineSegment` in the `Line`, and I need to make sure there is no conflict between line segments.

The architecture is like below:

```
public static class Line {
    private struct LineSegment {
        public LineSegment(int start, int end) {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }

    public readonly int Start;
    public readonly int End;
    }

   // User created LineSegment
   static public LineSegment Segment1() {
       return new LineSegment(1, 2);
   }

   static public LineSegment Segment2() {
       return new LineSegment(3, 6);
   }
}
```

And when users want to access their line segments, they can only access like:

```
int start = Line.Segment1.Start;
int end = Line.Segment1.End;
```

The reason that I make `LineSegment` to be `private` is that: I only want to users create and access `LineSegment` through static functions in `Line`, e.g. `Segment1`, `Segment2`. So that I can add a unit test using reflection to get all the methods in `Line`, and get all the line segments' start and end, then I can judge whether there is conflict between line segments.

If `LineSegment` is public, users can hack in their code just using: `new Line.LineSegment(2, 5)`, and I can't detect it through unit test. I don't want them create `LineSegment` outside `Line`.

But making `LineSegment` is dis-allowed in C# because of **inconsistent accessibility**. Is their any solution that can meets my requirment? Thanks!

Comment: actually not, other one can still directly construct `LineSegment` if their code is under this solution.

Comment: But `Segment1` and `Segment2` can't construct the `LineSegment` too?

Comment: if they have access to the solution, they can simply remove the private modifier ... i'd think: if the programmer does dumb things, then let him do dumb things... on the other hand ... why don't you make the LineSegment constructor take a Line parameter, or have a factory build LineSegments and have your checks done at runtime?

Comment: Yes, there are. But the compiler says the constructor is inaccessible due to its protection level. I think its because the private constructor can't been callled?

Comment: Yes, you comment makes sense. If they have access to the solution, they can simply remove the private modifier... But I think don't give them the access of `LineSegment` will give them a promt to use the function like `Segment1`... (If they construct `LineSegment`, I can not even find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about: give them access but warn them...

```
    public static class Line {
        public struct LineSegment {
            [Obsolete("DO NOT USE THIS DIRECTLY...")]
            public LineSegment(int start, int end) {
                Start = start;
                End = end;
            }

        public readonly int Start;
        public readonly int End;
        }

       // User created LineSegment
       static public LineSegment Segment1() {
           return _CreateSegment(1, 2);
       }

       static public LineSegment Segment2() {
           return _CreateSegment(3, 6);
       }

       static private LineSegment _CreateSegment(int start,int end) {
//we don't want to trigger the warning ...
#pragma warning disable 618
           return new LineSegment(3, 6);
#pragma warning restore 618
       }
    }
```

Comment: The function `_CreateSegment` will also trigger a warning for its return type is `LineSegment`...

Comment: does it help to disable 618 for the whole method?

Comment: Yes, it helps. But not seems beatiful.

Answer (score 2):

A well tried pattern in these cases is to define a public interface and keep the inner class private, with a public (or internal) constructor. In these way, you prevent other developers (and even yourself in the future) who work on the same project to call the constructor directly, while still giving them access to the relevant properties of the class.
So, first define the interface:

```
public interface ILineSegment
{
    int Start { get; }
    int End { get; }
}
```

and then your class:

```
public static class Line
{
    private struct LineSegment : ILineSegment
    {
        public int Start { get; }
        public int End { get; }

        public LineSegment(int start, int end)
        {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }
    }

    // User created LineSegment
    static public ILineSegment Segment1()
    {
        return new LineSegment(1, 2);
    }

    static public ILineSegment Segment2()
    {
        return new LineSegment(3, 6);
    }
```

Note that the return values of LineSegment1 and LineSegment2 have been changed from LineSegment (which is private, and cannot be returned by a public method) to ILineSegment, which is public, and can be returned.

Comment: Yes it's a good idea, but I think DarkSquirrel42's idea can avoid adding a interface and less change of code.

Answer (score 0):

After comparasion and ask for some opinions, finally I choosed to use `Environment.StackTrace.Contains` to meet my requirement.

```
public static class Line {
    public struct LineSegment {
        public LineSegment(int start, int end) {
            if (!Environment.StackTrace.Contains("MyNamespace.Line") || !Environment.StackTrace.Contains("UnitTest")) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Outside code is not allowed to call its constructor. Please construct your property in this file refering to the example.");
            }

            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }

        public readonly int Start;
        public readonly int End;
    }

   // User created LineSegment
   static public LineSegment Segment1() {
       return new LineSegment(1, 2);
   }

   static public LineSegment Segment2() {
       return new LineSegment(3, 6);
   }
}
```